# Using kong api gateway jwt plugin with django microservices

Tags: django, jwt, microservices, api-gateway, kong

I am currently playing around with the Kong API Gateway and I would like to use it to validate the authentication and the authorization of users at the gateway and restrict access to services if the user is not logged in properly.

I have already an existing authentication django microservice which issues JWTs whenever a user logs in but i cant share this tokens with the other microservices because each one of them have his own database.

So i would now like to know if i can share the JWT secret produced by django and use it for jwt plugin of kong api and also do i need to create a consumer for every users and what is the right steps to achieve that ?

Any hint would be highly appreciated.

Comment: JWT should not be seen as a secret, you just need to share the public key to validate them. Kong can be used to validate it. And also each microservice should validate it (no trust architecture).

Comment: sorry i couldn't understand what you mean by that

Comment: Django is not producing a secret, it is using a secret to sign the JWT itself. To validate the JWT you need to have the public part of the secret. No need to share the database.